# SimpleCursorAdapter list not displaying

Tags: android, arraylist, simplecursoradapter, android-listfragment

My SimpleCursorAdapter does not display any data from the ArrayList that I pass into it! Why is this and how do I fix it?

Here's my ListFragment, you can see the SimpleCursorAdapter being used in the onViewCreated() method.

```
public class CourseListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelper;

private static String courseName;
ArrayList<String> courseItems;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public CourseListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    courseItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] projection = new String[] {DbHelper.COURSE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID};
    String[] from = new String[] { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    int[] to = new int[] { getListView().getId() };
    int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
            : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), layout, cursor, from, to, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    // The problem starts here
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
            getListView(),
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.OnDismissCallback() {
                public void onDismiss(ListView listView,
                        int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                        removeCourse(position);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            });
    getListView().setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
        courseItems.add(courseName);
    }
    c.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addCourse() {
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToLast();
    courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
    courseItems.add(courseName);
    c.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeCourse(int position) {
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.C_ID, DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID + "=" + position,
            null);
    c.close();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(null);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

public void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

Thanks! Much appreciated!

****Edit: Updated code using SimpleCursorAdapter****

```
public class CourseListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {

SQLiteDatabase db;
DbHelper dbHelper;

private static String courseName;
ArrayList<String> courseItems;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
/**
 * The serialization (saved instance state) Bundle key representing the
 * activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

/**
 * The fragment's current callback object, which is notified of list item
 * clicks.
 */
private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

/**
 * The current activated item position. Only used on tablets.
 */
private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

/**
 * A callback interface that all activities containing this fragment must
 * implement. This mechanism allows activities to be notified of item
 * selections.
 */
public interface Callbacks {
    /**
     * Callback for when an item has been selected.
     */
    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

/**
 * A dummy implementation of the {@link Callbacks} interface that does
 * nothing. Used only when this fragment is not attached to an activity.
 */
private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

/**
 * Mandatory empty constructor for the fragment manager to instantiate the
 * fragment (e.g. upon screen orientation changes).
 */
public CourseListFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null
            && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(getActivity());
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    courseItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    final String[] projection = new String[] {DbHelper.COURSE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
    // Fields on the UI to which we map
    final String[] from = new String[] { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.internalEmpty };
    final int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
            : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), layout, cursor, from, to, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    // The problem starts here
    SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener touchListener = new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener(
            getListView(),
            new SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener.OnDismissCallback() {
                public void onDismiss(ListView listView,
                        int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                    for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                        removeCourse(position);
                        Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null, null, null);
                        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), layout, c, from, to, SimpleCursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                }
            });
    getListView().setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    getListView().setOnScrollListener(touchListener.makeScrollListener());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c.moveToNext()) {
        courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
        courseItems.add(courseName);
    }
    c.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addCourse() {
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToLast();
    courseName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.COURSE_NAME));
    courseItems.add(courseName);
    c.close();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void removeCourse(int position) {
    String[] projection = { DbHelper.C_ID, DbHelper.COURSE_NAME };
    Cursor c = db.query(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, projection, null, null, null,
            null, null);
    c.moveToPosition(position);
    db.delete(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, DbHelper.C_ID + "=" + position,
            null);
    c.close();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    // Notify the active callbacks interface (the activity, if the
    // fragment is attached to one) that an item has been selected.
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(null);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        // Serialize and persist the activated item position.
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

/**
 * Turns on activate-on-click mode. When this mode is on, list items will be
 * given the 'activated' state when touched.
 */
public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) {
    // When setting CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE, ListView will automatically
    // give items the 'activated' state when touched.
    getListView().setChoiceMode(
            activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
                    : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

public void setActivatedPosition(int position) {
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
}
}
```

Comment: check whether courseItems has any data

Comment: I add items to courseItems from another activity.

Comment: What does `DbHelper.C_ID` represent? If you use a `Cursor` with `SimpleCursorAdapter` for something like a `ListView`, one of the columns must be called `_id` - notice the underscore and also lower-case.

Comment: DbHelper.C_ID represents "_id"

Comment: Oh well, sorry I can't think of anything else other than the fact you call `close()` on your `Cursors`. Remember a `SimpleCursorAdapter` needs an open `Cursor` to work correctly - the adapter itself doesn't maintain the data and relies on the `Cursor`. Comment out all the calls to `close()` on your `Cursors` and see if that helps.

Comment: sorry that didn't work either. this is an interesting question. maybe it has to do with the flag that I put in for the SimpleCursorAdapter constructer? Should I use a cursorloader instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int[] to = new int[] { getListView().getId() };
```

that line is wrong. and i cant imagine what's happening behind the scenes. the `int[] to` is supposed to be for example

```
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.text1};
```

the id of the `textView` in the `int layout` parameter that you passed to the SimpleCursorAdapter, that you want the columns of `String[] from` to be written to. i suggest you find out the textView id contents of:

```
int layout = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) ? android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1
            : android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
```

Then make a conditional statement just like that.

---

**EDIT** use the following line

```
int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
```

Comment: I am using the master/detail flow template right now. It references a fragment whose layout is is android:list_content. I imported the list_content.xml into my project and reference the textview inside list_content. It still DOESN'T WORKKKKKKKKKKKKK. haha thanks though

Comment: and you changed the `int layout` too? these are supposed to represent an xml layout to be inflated for each row of your listview

Comment: why would i need to change the int layout? If the sdk version is >= 11, use the activated state, and if not, use simple_list_item_1

Comment: I still don't see why I would need to change the int layout.

Comment: the `layout` and `to` are linked. They **cannot** be non-corresponding entries. `to` references a textview **inside** the layout. The layout is an xml that will be repeated for each row of your listview. You are using an android provided layout xml(s), ***but not** referencing the textview inside, so it's there but blank. Since you're adamant about using those layouts (contra-indicated by your list_content.xml line above) use the `int[] to` line edit above.

Comment: okay, I'm referencing the textview inside. I copied list_content.xml into my project and made all the id's come from my project. However, I'm having a problem where the list item is blank but being added and not being deleted, meaning when I swipe to dismiss it, it comes right back. Btw, thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: sorry for my one track mind, but was this problem solved? you can see in items on your list now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20669/discussion-between-mango-and-aindurti)